# does hibernate support to run MERGE statement or not?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

when  I execute the below native query :

```
String sql="merge into omfx.OM_PART_LOOKUP   toLookup\r\n" + 
        "           using omfx.OM_PART_LOOKUP fromLookup\r\n" + 
        "               on(\r\n" + 
        "                 toLookup.PROJECT_ID= "+toProjectID+" and \r\n" + 
        "                 fromLookup.PROJECT_ID= "+fromProjectId +" and  \r\n" + 
        "                 toLookup.scope =0 and \r\n" + 
        "                 UPPER(toLookup.PN)  =  UPPER(fromLookup.PN) and\r\n" + 
        "                 UPPER(toLookup.MAN)  =  UPPER(fromLookup.MAN)\r\n" + 
        "                )\r\n" + 
        "           when matched then update \r\n" + 
        "               set \r\n" + 
        "             \r\n" + 
        "             toLookup.SEPN = fromLookup.SEPN ,\r\n" + 
        "             toLookup.SE_MAN_ID = fromLookup.SE_MAN_ID ,\r\n" + 
        "             toLookup.COM_ID = fromLookup.COM_ID ,\r\n" + 
        "             toLookup.SE_MAN_NAME = fromLookup.SE_MAN_NAME ,\r\n" + 
        "             toLookup.PART_CATEGORY = fromLookup.PART_CATEGORY \r\n" + 
        "             \r\n" + 
        "             \r\n" + 
        "            when NOT matched then \r\n" + 
        "            insert (PN,MAN,SEPN, SE_MAN_ID, COM_ID,SE_MAN_NAME ,PART_CATEGORY ,INSERT_DATE,PROJECT_ID)\r\n" + 
        "             values (fromLookup.PN,fromLookup.MAN,fromLookup.SEPN, fromLookup.SE_MAN_ID, fromLookup.COM_ID , fromLookup.SE_MAN_NAME ,fromLookup.PART_CATEGORY , SYSDATE,"+toProjectID+") where\r\n" + 
        "             fromLookup.PROJECT_ID = "+fromProjectId+" and fromLookup.scope = 0\r\n" + 
        "            ";

    System.out.println("projectOperationsBean.mergeManLookup()::sql=="+sql);
     em.createNativeQuery(sql).getSingleResult();
```

I found the below error

Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.2.v20130514-5956486): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Error Code: 0

but when I execute this query in oracle ,It run good

does hibernate support to run MERGE statement or not?

Comment: Thats have nothing to do with hibernate. Your are executing this query in a wrong way. First remove all those `\r\n` from the query string. Second, make sure that those concatenations is being done right (and by the way this is the wrong way of doing it, you should use prepared statements).

Comment: Also, this is a statement that should be executed with executeUpdate not getSingleResult

Comment: @JorgeCampos: the `\r\n` is not a problem, Oracle can handle that without problems.

Comment: @JorgeCampos: Issue solved by executeUpdate not getSingleResult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks @Jorge Campos

`MERGE` is a DML statement so I must execute `.executeUpdate()` not  `.getSingleResult()`